# AWS: disable default domain name for alb

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

Using a containerized app which is linked with an application load balancer to route traffic from port 80 to 443 and also handle health check and scaling.

But the issue is the application load balancer when created both through the console and the cli gets assigned default dns name.
Which is something im trying to get rid of, since i have a dns record in route53 to forward traffic to the alb.
And my end goal is for the app to be aviable only through my domain name.

What im interested is either how to disable the default dns name for my alb

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that. Your ALB needs a DNS name, so you can point your Route53 record to it. When publishing your app, you can use your custom domain name, but the app will stay available at the ALB DNS name.

Comment: What would the alternative be, ignore alb all together, setup nginx and have it handle https?

Comment: What is the problem with your application being available at another DNS name? If you don't promote it, no one will even notice it.

Comment: Its absolutely not acceptable as an enterprise grade software to have a dns record that not only pinpoints the host provider but furthermore the exact region.

Comment: If you really want to prevent that, you can use an NLB, which gives you an IP address that you can point your Route53 record to. But that comes at a cost. Indicating the region your application is deployed into is a good thing, especially with GDPR regulations. And if you‘re worried that your users won‘t like that you‘re using AWS, then you really shouldn‘t use AWS.